# How to use Geo bounds query and match query together using elastic search sql queries?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, geolocation

I use the elastic search match SQL queries for get the result. but i want the results which have example like name matches with "abc" and it also fall in particular map location geo bounds using sql query.

I using sql select match query and that give result correct on basis of name. but i need a result on basis of map bounds also. i need a single SQL queries for get the result on basis of both condition.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [geo function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-functions-geo.html) inside the SQL of Elasticsearch. Did you check them? But these functions are in **beta**. So, you can find a full list  the future development in here :

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/48521

Also, you can check this page. There are some limitations to the SQL feature of Elasticsearch.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-limitations.html#geo-sql-limitations